# AngularJs + IE9 + ng-include + html5Mode = page reload?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to get routing working with angular 1.2.16 in IE 9. However, I notice that with an ng-include on my page, everything breaks. If I remove just the ng-include, simple routes work (e.g., routes with no parameters). Complex routes are still broken, though. If I don't turn on Html5Mode, ng-include works fine. Is there a way to have both?

I reproduced the issue in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q55UR/3/
Notice how if I comment out either html5Mode OR ng-include, the rest of the stuff works:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
OR
`<div ng-include src="coursesTemplateId"></div>`

Sidenote: The complex routes breaking could be related to my framework too (MVC 4) - I would love to be pointed to resources on getting IE9 + angularJs routing in MVC 4 with parameters in the route.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417 - "ngInclude ... depends on $anchorScroll, which depends on $location - maybe fixing this dependency should be a separate issue... (to be investigated)"

Answer (score -1):

It will never work with IE9. html5Mode uses html5 history not supported by IE9.

Comment: html5mode in angular provides an automatic fallback to url hashes in browsers that don't have pushstate support